# Combining 3D graphics with different lighting conditions

Tags: graphics3d, lighting

I would like to create a 3D graphic of the bust of Beethoven with specified lighting position, as well as a small (colored) set of axes.  I would like the axes to *not* be affected by the position of the light in the rest of the figure.

```
bustWithLight = Show[ExampleData[{"Geometry3D","Beethoven"}],
  Lighting -> {{"Directional", 
                 RGBColor[1, 1, 1], {0, -20, -20}}}]
```

[image]

Here are the axes:

```
theAxes = Graphics3D[
  {Red, Thickness[0.015], Arrowheads[.05],
   Arrow[Tube[{{-3.5, -.5, 0}, {-3.5, -2.5, 0}}]],
   Green,
   Arrow[Tube[{{-3.5, -.5, 0}, {-3.5, -.5, 2}}]],
   Blue,
   Arrow[Tube[{{-3.5, -.5, 0}, {-5.5, -.5, 0}}]]},
  Lighting -> {"Ambient", White}]
```

[image]

Here they are integrated:

```
Show[bustWithLight, theAxes]
```

[image]

***Problem***:  Notice that the axes are rendered as three-dimensional tubes (as they should) but "illuminated" by the lighting inherited from the bust.  (This is clearest if you render then rotate the whole figure on your screen.)  I would like to render the axes so they have no such inherited illumination.

I have tried a number of methods (such as above), but it seems that a final `Show` demands there be a *single* overall lighting.  Is there a way to avoid this limitation?

Comment: You could try to `Inset` the inner `Graphics3D`.

Comment: @b3m2a1:  `Inset` doesn't seem to work.  I've posted all my code.  Can you just cut and paste and verify `Inset` works for you?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `Lighting` as a directive:

```
theAxes2 = Graphics3D[{Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}},  Thickness[0.015], 
    Red, Arrowheads[.05], Arrow[Tube[{{-3.5, -.5, 0}, {-3.5, -2.5, 0}}]], 
    Green, Arrow[Tube[{{-3.5, -.5, 0}, {-3.5, -.5, 2}}]],
    Blue,  Arrow[Tube[{{-3.5, -.5, 0}, {-5.5, -.5, 0}}]]}];

Show[bustWithLight, theAxes2]
```

[image]

An alternative way to give each primitive its own lighting directives is to use `Style[primitivei, Lighting -> lightingi]`:

```
theAxes3 = Graphics3D[{Thickness[0.015], Arrowheads[.05],
   MapThread[Style[#, #2, Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}]&, 
     {{Arrow[Tube[{{-3.5, -.5, 0}, {-3.5, -2.5, 0}}]], 
       Arrow[Tube[{{-3.5, -.5, 0}, {-3.5, -.5, 2}}]], 
       Arrow[Tube[{{-3.5, -.5, 0}, {-5.5, -.5, 0}}]]}, 
     {Red, Green, Blue}}]}];

Show[bustWithLight, theAxes3]
```

> same picture

Both usages are documented in [`Lighting >> Details`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Lighting.html)

[image]

Comment: Oh... you are very good at this.  Thanks so much.  ($\checkmark$)

Comment: @David, thank you for the accept.